# Deletar chave se todos os valores forem vazios

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript

Possuo um array de objetos JavaScript e queria verificar se determinadas chaves/colunas possuem o valor "" (vazio). Se sim deletar essa chave do meu array de Objeto JavaScript, caso contrário, manter o mesmo.

Segue um Array de Objeto JavaScript como exemplo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gAIRutLHYS1UZwHXaKVqQmv4bRsg3fy1/view?usp=sharing

A imagem do banco de dados reflete melhor o que eu espero obter como resultados.
Os dados são os mesmos que estão no link acima.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz o código abaixo, mas ele faz uma verificação linha a linha e deleta a linha caso ela esteja vazia.

```
public filterColumns(productConfig: ProductConfig[]) {

        for (let i = 0; i < productConfig.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
                if (productConfig[i]['Attr_Val_' + j] === "") {
                    delete productConfig[i]['Attr_Val_' + j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Precisava verificar se TODAS as linhas estão vazias antes de deletar a chave/coluna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz dois laços, como você fez, mas criando uma array separada adicionando os nomes das chaves vazias em todos os objetos. Em seguida faz mais dois laços deletando os nomes das chaves que foram guardadas na array.

```js
const productConfig = [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "Country": "Brazil",
  "Tier": "",
  "IBX": "RJ1",
  "PriceList": "BR - Price List",
  "PriceListDescription": "BR - Price List",
  "UOM": "Each",
  "Currency": "BRL",
  "LastPrice": 0.00,
  "AdjustmentType": "Price Override",
  "AdjustmentAmount": 4458.29,
  "EffectiveStartDate": "0000-00-00",
  "EffectiveEndDate": "0000-00-00",
  "Product": "Workstation Seat",
  "PartNumber": "BC00002.ELEM",
  "Attribute_1": "BCTR Room Type",
  "Attr_Val_1": "BCTR-DEDICATED",
  "Operator_1": "",
  "Attribute_2": "Workstation Seat Type",
  "Attr_Val_2": "Back Office",
  "Operator_2": "",
  "Attribute_3": "",
  "Attr_Val_3": "",
  "Operator_3": "",
  "Attribute_4": "",
  "Attr_Val_4": "",
  "Operator_4": "",
  "Attribute_5": "",
  "Attr_Val_5": "",
  "Operator_5": "",
  "Attribute_6": "",
  "Attr_Val_6": "",
  "Operator_6": "",
  "DeleteRule": "",
  "Resale": "",
  "AccountCategory": ""
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "Country": "Brazil",
  "Tier": "",
  "IBX": "RJ1",
  "PriceList": "BR - Price List",
  "PriceListDescription": "BR - Price List",
  "UOM": "Each",
  "Currency": "BRL",
  "LastPrice": 0.00,
  "AdjustmentType": "Price Override",
  "AdjustmentAmount": 2229.14,
  "EffectiveStartDate": "0000-00-00",
  "EffectiveEndDate": "0000-00-00",
  "Product": "Workstation Seat - Installation Fee",
  "PartNumber": "BC00002.NR",
  "Attribute_1": "BCTR Room Type",
  "Attr_Val_1": "BCTR-DEDICATED",
  "Operator_1": "",
  "Attribute_2": "Workstation Seat Type",
  "Attr_Val_2": "Back Office",
  "Operator_2": "",
  "Attribute_3": "",
  "Attr_Val_3": "",
  "Operator_3": "",
  "Attribute_4": "",
  "Attr_Val_4": "",
  "Operator_4": "",
  "Attribute_5": "",
  "Attr_Val_5": "",
  "Operator_5": "",
  "Attribute_6": "",
  "Attr_Val_6": "",
  "Operator_6": "",
  "DeleteRule": "",
  "Resale": "",
  "AccountCategory": ""
 },
 {
  "id": 3,
  "Country": "Brazil",
  "Tier": "",
  "IBX": "RJ2",
  "PriceList": "BR - Price List",
  "PriceListDescription": "BR - Price List",
  "UOM": "Each",
  "Currency": "BRL",
  "LastPrice": 0.00,
  "AdjustmentType": "Price Override",
  "AdjustmentAmount": 4293.60,
  "EffectiveStartDate": "0000-00-00",
  "EffectiveEndDate": "0000-00-00",
  "Product": "Workstation Seat",
  "PartNumber": "BC00002.ELEM",
  "Attribute_1": "BCTR Room Type",
  "Attr_Val_1": "BCTR-DEDICATED",
  "Operator_1": "",
  "Attribute_2": "Workstation Seat Type",
  "Attr_Val_2": "Back Office",
  "Operator_2": "",
  "Attribute_3": "",
  "Attr_Val_3": "",
  "Operator_3": "",
  "Attribute_4": "",
  "Attr_Val_4": "",
  "Operator_4": "",
  "Attribute_5": "",
  "Attr_Val_5": "",
  "Operator_5": "",
  "Attribute_6": "",
  "Attr_Val_6": "",
  "Operator_6": "",
  "DeleteRule": "",
  "Resale": "",
  "AccountCategory": ""
 },
 {
  "id": 4,
  "Country": "Brazil",
  "Tier": "",
  "IBX": "RJ2",
  "PriceList": "BR - Price List",
  "PriceListDescription": "BR - Price List",
  "UOM": "Each",
  "Currency": "BRL",
  "LastPrice": 0.00,
  "AdjustmentType": "Price Override",
  "AdjustmentAmount": 2146.80,
  "EffectiveStartDate": "0000-00-00",
  "EffectiveEndDate": "0000-00-00",
  "Product": "Workstation Seat - Installation Fee",
  "PartNumber": "BC00002.NR",
  "Attribute_1": "BCTR Room Type",
  "Attr_Val_1": "BCTR-DEDICATED",
  "Operator_1": "",
  "Attribute_2": "Workstation Seat Type",
  "Attr_Val_2": "Back Office",
  "Operator_2": "",
  "Attribute_3": "",
  "Attr_Val_3": "",
  "Operator_3": "",
  "Attribute_4": "",
  "Attr_Val_4": "",
  "Operator_4": "",
  "Attribute_5": "",
  "Attr_Val_5": "",
  "Operator_5": "",
  "Attribute_6": "",
  "Attr_Val_6": "",
  "Operator_6": "",
  "DeleteRule": "",
  "Resale": "",
  "AccountCategory": ""
 },
 {
  "id": 5,
  "Country": "Brazil",
  "Tier": "",
  "IBX": "SP1",
  "PriceList": "BR - Price List",
  "PriceListDescription": "BR - Price List",
  "UOM": "Each",
  "Currency": "BRL",
  "LastPrice": 0.00,
  "AdjustmentType": "Price Override",
  "AdjustmentAmount": 4376.16,
  "EffectiveStartDate": "0000-00-00",
  "EffectiveEndDate": "0000-00-00",
  "Product": "Workstation Seat",
  "PartNumber": "BC00002.ELEM",
  "Attribute_1": "BCTR Room Type",
  "Attr_Val_1": "BCTR-DEDICATED",
  "Operator_1": "",
  "Attribute_2": "Workstation Seat Type",
  "Attr_Val_2": "Back Office",
  "Operator_2": "",
  "Attribute_3": "",
  "Attr_Val_3": "",
  "Operator_3": "",
  "Attribute_4": "",
  "Attr_Val_4": "",
  "Operator_4": "",
  "Attribute_5": "",
  "Attr_Val_5": "",
  "Operator_5": "",
  "Attribute_6": "",
  "Attr_Val_6": "",
  "Operator_6": "",
  "DeleteRule": "",
  "Resale": "",
  "AccountCategory": ""
 },
 {
  "id": 6,
  "Country": "Brazil",
  "Tier": "",
  "IBX": "SP1",
  "PriceList": "BR - Price List",
  "PriceListDescription": "BR - Price List",
  "UOM": "Each",
  "Currency": "BRL",
  "LastPrice": 0.00,
  "AdjustmentType": "Price Override",
  "AdjustmentAmount": 2188.08,
  "EffectiveStartDate": "0000-00-00",
  "EffectiveEndDate": "0000-00-00",
  "Product": "Workstation Seat - Installation Fee",
  "PartNumber": "BC00002.NR",
  "Attribute_1": "BCTR Room Type",
  "Attr_Val_1": "BCTR-DEDICATED",
  "Operator_1": "",
  "Attribute_2": "Workstation Seat Type",
  "Attr_Val_2": "Back Office",
  "Operator_2": "",
  "Attribute_3": "",
  "Attr_Val_3": "",
  "Operator_3": "",
  "Attribute_4": "",
  "Attr_Val_4": "",
  "Operator_4": "",
  "Attribute_5": "",
  "Attr_Val_5": "",
  "Operator_5": "",
  "Attribute_6": "",
  "Attr_Val_6": "",
  "Operator_6": "",
  "DeleteRule": "",
  "Resale": "",
  "AccountCategory": ""
 }];


let deletar = [];

for (let i = 0; i < productConfig.length; i++) {
   for (let j in productConfig[i]) {
      let x = deletar.indexOf(j);
      if(productConfig[i][j] === "" && !~x){
         deletar.push(j); // adiciona o nome da chave vazia
      }else if(productConfig[i][j] !== "" && ~x){
         // remove da array se tiver valor alguma chave vazia que foi adicionada antes
         deletar.splice(x,1);
      }
   }
}

for (let i = 0; i < productConfig.length; i++) {
   for(let d of deletar) delete productConfig[i][d];
}

console.log("Colunas deletadas", deletar); // chaves vazias
console.log(productConfig); // json tratado
```